# Add all the elements in an array without using loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to add elements without using loops and the built-in method of the array like for , foreach etc) and built in methods(like reduce,map...) of array
How can we do the addition?

```
var arr =[1,2,2,3,4...];
```

arr length also dynamic.

Comment: can you explain why you can't use loops or any of the array methods?

Comment: `arr.push(123)` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: assuming youtrying to add elements of one array into another - `arr1 = [...arr1,...arr2]` or `arr1.push(...arr2)`

Comment: When you say "add" do you mean to calculate the total sum of all the numbers in your array, or to append/extend your array with new values?

Comment: Does push count?

Comment: _If_ I understood what you want to achieve and you do not want to use neither loops nor built-in array methods, you can use a recursive function like this: https://jsfiddle.net/7rf8wqLo/ (or something similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Spread ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) operator like this

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [5,6,7,8];
console.log([...arr1, ...arr2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat for that whice creates a new array and returns the result so arr1 and arr2 will remain unchanged.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2];
const arr2 = [3, 4,5,6,7,8];
const combined = arr1.concat(arr2);

console.log(combined);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

If you want to mutate the original array you can use push and the spread operator (...):

```js
const a = [1,2]
const b = [3,4,5,6]
a.push(...b)

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition as in sum?

```js
const arr = [1,2,2,3,4];
// normal way
let sum = arr.reduce((a,b) => a+b)
console.log(sum)
// weird way not using loops but still using a built-in method
sum = eval(arr.toString().replace(/,/g,"+"))
console.log(sum)
```